# warning on bmake

Tags: c, makefile

```
bmake: "Makefile" line 20: warning: duplicate script for target "xyz" ignored
bmake: "Makefile" line 10: warning: using previous script for "xyz" defined here
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Think you can you include the makefile in your question? It would be helpful to those trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `<target>`s. Their name-attributes must contain unique values.

Comment: yesss, thats the issue. Its doing the thing that I asked it to, just vomiting this junk, anyways, thanks :)